# pandas converts long decimal string into "-inf"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, floating-point

I have a CSV with a float value represented as a long decimal string (a -1 followed by 342 0's). Example below:

```
ID,AMOUNT
"id_1","-1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

The issue is that, when reading into a pandas (`0.25`) DataFrame, the value automatically gets converted to a `-inf`:

```py
>>> pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv')['AMOUNT']
0   -inf
Name: AMOUNT, dtype: float64
```

If I change the value in the CSV to a `"-1.0"`, it works fine as expected. Weirdly, there seems to be a sweet spot regarding how long the string can be. If I manually truncate the string to only 308 0's, it reads in the value correctly as a -1.0:

```py
# when value is "-1.0" or "-1." followed by 308 0's
>>> pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv')['AMOUNT']
0   -1.0
Name: AMOUNT, dtype: float64
```

While the ideal solution would be to ensure that value is truncated in the source itself before we process it. But in the meanwhile, what is the reason for this behavior? and/or is there a workaround for this?

We are currently using Python 3.6 and Pandas 0.25

Comment: Have you tried upgrading pandas? I cannot reproduce your issue with the latest version of pandas

Comment: Yea, it seems to work with the latest version of pandas. Although it would be preferred to get it working with 0.25 before resorting to upgrading version, mainly because that would cause other conflicting dependency issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround might be to read in the columns as strings, then truncate the trailing zeros using the built-in float function.

```
df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/file.csv", dtype="string")
df['AMOUNT'] = df['AMOUNT'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
```